# ¿Como puedo ajustar el tamaño de cada columna en una tabla de iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itextsharp

Estoy creando esta tabla a partir de una base de datos con iTextSharp, mi duda es como puedo ajustar la columna del id para que quede mas ajustado a su tamaño, ya que me ocupa un tamaño por defecto cada una de ellas.

El codigo que que uso para crear la tabla

```
   private void GenerarTabla(Document doc, Font fontNormal, int id, DateTime fechaInicio, DateTime fechaFin)
    {
     var lista = db.Pedido.Where(x => x.Vigente == true && x.Fecha >= fechaInicio && x.Fecha <= fechaFin).ToList();

     PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(8) { WidthPercentage = 90 };
              

            // Esta es la primera fila
            table.AddCell(new Phrase("#", font1));
            table.AddCell(new Phrase("Numero de Pedido", font1));
            table.AddCell(new Phrase("Cliente", font1));
            table.AddCell(new Phrase("Fecha del Pedido", font1));
            table.AddCell(new Phrase("Fecha de Entrega", font1));
            table.AddCell(new Phrase("Forma de Pago", font1));
            table.AddCell(new Phrase("Notas del Pedido", font1));
            table.AddCell(new Phrase("Estado", font1));

            foreach (var item in lista)
            {

                //filas
                table.AddCell(new Phrase("" + item.IdPedido, font1));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase("" + item.Numero, font1));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase("" + item.Cliente.Nombre, font1));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase("" + item.Fecha.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"), font1));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase("" + item.FechaEntrega.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"), font1));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase("" + item.FormaPago.Nombre, font1));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase("" + item.NotasPedido, font1));
                table.AddCell(new Phrase("" + item.Estado.Nombre, font1));

            }
            doc.Add(table); 
    }
```

Este es el resultado actual que tengo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En ITextSharp, las tablas tienen un metodo SetWidths. Puedes usar ese método para cambiar el tamaño de las columnas.

Éste método recibe un array de floats. (Un tamaño por cada celda).

Como tal, no puedes cambiar el tamaño de las celdas individualmente, con lo cual, deberás de establecer el ancho de todas y cada una de las columnas.

Ejemplo:

```cs
float[] width = new float[] { 1f, 2f }; // Aqui estamos diciendo que la segunda columna sea de 2 unidades y la primera de 1. En tu caso deberias de hacer esto mismo pero con el tamaño de cada una de las celdas.
table.SetWidths(widths);
```

Comment: Gracias bro voy a probarlo

Comment: Gracias bro tu respuesta me ayudo con mi problema

Comment: Si quieres, marcalo como respuesta